# Getting Could not generate DH keypair Exception

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, vcenter

I am getting this exception when vCenter(5.5) try to download zip file from a https server. VCenter server has JRE 1.6.0.31. I am aware of bug related to same issue in Java 1.6 and 1.7. This exception is caused by  `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)`.

I can change the SSL certificate from the https server. I tried to solve this issue by generating new certificates with OpenSSL (`openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:1024 -days 365 -out server.crt -extensions usr_cert`
) and other options as well. I looked into `sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker` code, There is switch case which executes
following lines of code and generate exception.

```
case K_DHE_DSS:
case K_DHE_RSA:
    this.serverKeyExchange(new DH_ServerKeyExchange(input, serverKey,
    clnt_random.random_bytes, svr_random.random_bytes,messageLen));
```

is there any way to generate SSL certificate which will avoid this code execution (may be, SSL certificate without DH keypair) ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyexchange is DHE_RSA which means Diffie Hellman *Ephemeral* authenticated by RSA. The DHE key, and even the DHE parameters, are **not in the certificate**, which is longterm (FSVO long) not ephemeral. The key in the certificate is RSA, and Java has no problem dealing with RSA at secure sizes, which today is more than 1024 and conventionally 2048.

1. The direct fix is to use old-Java-compatible weak **DH(E) parameters**. There are probably a dozen or more SSL/TLS server programs that use OpenSSL, or otherwise use PEM format files for the cert *and* (RSA) privatekey. (*Lots* of software uses or can handle PEM for *cert*, but mostly OpenSSL does so for privatekey.) Many of these server programs allow configuring the DH(E) parameters, but all that I've seen do so differently, and you don't identify yours.
2. A workaround is to avoid DHE_anything and use **plain-RSA** keyexchange. All SSL/TLS implementations including OpenSSL implement this. However, most applications and/or middlewares no longer prefer it and some don't even allow it, because it doesn't provide [Forward Secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy). How you control the ciphersuites, and thus keyexchange, again depends on the unidentified server program.
3. A better workaround is to enable **ECDHE** (and specifically ECDHE_RSA, since your cert/key is RSA) if you can.

   3A. Java6 JSSE implements ECDHE protocols, but enables them only if there is a JCE "provider" for ECC primitives in your JRE -- and Oracle/Sun JRE6 as delivered (and TTBOMK the OpenJDK one also) does not have an ECC provider. To **add ECC provider** to JRE6

   - download `bcprov-jdk15on-$version.jar` from http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html and put it in your `JRE/lib/ext`
   - edit `JRE/lib/security/java.security` to add to the list of providers a line like `security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider` where N is the next available number.

   JRE7 does include ECC provider, and supports ECDHE out-of-the-box, if that is an option.

   3B. If your server uses OpenSSL 1.0.0 or higher (except for certain older RedHat builds) it implements ECDHE, but it can be *used only if* (1) the ciphersuites are enabled, which is true by default but could be disabled by the server program or its configuration, *and* (2) the server program sets tmp_ecdh parameters (or in 1.0.2 enables auto-setting). Both of these depend on the unidentified server program, and if the server program doesn't use OpenSSL the answer may be very different.

If you **identify your server program** and the SSL/TLS-related parts of its configuration, I (or perhaps someone else) can be more specific.

**EDIT** server is **nginx**:

(1) nginx should be able to use DHE params Java(6,7) can handle, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_dhparam and create the file with

```
 openssl dhparam 1024 >mydhfile
```

(or if you really want, a smaller DSA-1 size = 512 to 1024 and a multiple of 64, but you don't need and I don't recommend smaller than 1024).

(2) alernatively, to disable DHE, *don't* add it but *do* add at least some kRSA (or just RSA) in the ssl_ciphers string. Change the string in your comment at least to

```
 EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH:kRSA:!RC4:!aNU‌​LL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS
```

or because unmodified JRE6 won't offer ECDHE (or TLSv1.2) and we haven't added any PSK or SRP or DSS or aNULL that need to be deleted, and you distrust 3DES (why?) and RC4 and Java doesn't implement SEED or Camellia, you could use much more simply just

```
 AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA
```

(These are actually TLS_RSA_WITH_AES*_CBC_SHA but for hysterical raisins the OpenSSL name omits the RSA, and the CBC.)

**Tomcat** by default uses Java (JSSE) to handle HTTPS connections, but depending on the packaging/install often can use APR also called "Tomcat native" or just "native" which is actually OpenSSL. If Tomcat/JSSE is run on JRE6 or 7, it uses DHE size 768 which JRE6,7 client can handle; if run on JRE8 it *defaults* to size 1024 which JRE6,7 client can handle. I don't know what Tomcat/APR uses (and can't easily test) but it could well be 1024 or less. If you want to find out and have Tomcat/APR running and openssl **1.0.2** available, use `openssl s_client -connect host:port -tls1 -cipher EDH+AES`; when it connects enter Q, return; and look about 20 lines up for "Server Temp Key".

Comment: Thanks Dave for answer, but we have hard luck ! 3rd approach is not applicable in my case as I am not allowed to modify JRE environment. I tried by generating cert and RSA key file in PEM format but it did not work as well. Do you have any pointer about how to generate plain-RSA keyexchange  (I have shared my openssl command in my quetion). My present HTTPS server is NGINX.  If I try same thing with tomcat in HTTPS mode, its working. Vcenter can download zip file from HTTPS tomcat.

Comment: on (HTTPS) nginx server configuration, I have following configuration 
ssl_ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EDH+aRSA:EECDH:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS;

Comment: @Bhushan as I said, it's not in the cert; DHE_RSA with any size DHE paramers uses the *same* RSA cert and key. For nginx (and tomcat) see edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave, new edits are really helpful and everything is working now !. I am newbie in SSL, so not aware of role DH keypair in SSL. Your answer helped in understanding. I changed in nginx.conf file and set ssl_dhparam to 1024 dh param file. I tried 2nd alternative as well by changing ssl_ciphers to default ones. Both the approaches are working.