# Unable to connect to mssql due to SSL error

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jboss

I have a small project that i am working on to practice and it worked perfectly until recently.
Today i tried to open up the server and make some work on the project and a error popped out of nowhere regarding SSL encryption even though i am not using it.
The only thing different is that i updated to Windows 10 a little while ago. The project is the same.

The server i am running the application is Jboss AS7

If there is any information i should mention and i didnt, please let me know and ill edit this post.

This is the error i am getting in the console:

```
19:37:40,459 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: LicentaJPA
...]
19:37:40,615 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
19:37:40,740 INFO  [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.internals.TDS.Channel] (MSC service thread 1-5) java.security path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\security
Security providers: [SUN version 1.6, SunRsaSign version 1.5, SunJSSE version 1.6, SunJCE version 1.6, SunJGSS version 1.0, SunSASL version 1.5, XMLDSig version 1.0, SunPCSC version 1.6, SunMSCAPI version 1.6]
SSLContext provider info: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509 key/trust factories, SSLv3, TLSv1)
SSLContext provider services:
[SunJSSE: KeyFactory.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
, SunJSSE: KeyPairGenerator.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyPairGenerator
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD2withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD2withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.2, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD5withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD5withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4]
, SunJSSE: Signature.SHA1withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA1withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, 1.3.14.3.2.29, OID.1.3.14.3.2.29]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD5andSHA1withRSA -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSASignature
, SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.SunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509
, SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.NewSunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$X509
, SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.SunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$SimpleFactory
, SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.PKIX -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$PKIXFactory
  aliases: [SunPKIX, X509, X.509]
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.SSL -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.SSLv3 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLS -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.Default -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: KeyStore.PKCS12 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore
]
java.ext.dirs: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
19:37:40,740 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (MSC service thread 1-5) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:235)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:761)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:343)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:253) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:119) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair". ClientConnectionId:ae700e8b-e96f-4c71-b9e5-017a92496cbd
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1668)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1323)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:249)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1708) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1691) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1222) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1618)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:114) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:559) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:186) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyPairGenerator.initialize(DashoA13*..)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.initialize(KeyPairGenerator.java:627) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:107) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    ... 44 more
```

Comment: Check this out. The solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851461/java-why-does-ssl-handshake-give-could-not-generate-dh-keypair-exception

Comment: This helps me :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230342/getting-could-not-generate-dh-keypair-exception